# Response Object coming null for get request for rest api

Tags: angularjs, rest, vonage

I am trying to implement nexmoverify REST API for OTP implementation but response object comig null.I checked in Postman and able to get stringify object from of response object.

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
   $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
   delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
}
]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {


   $scope.addNewChoice = function () {
      console.log('aaaa');
      $scope.res=$http.get("https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=56a9b1af&api_secret=XXXXXX&number=919650298011&brand=stayuncle").
         success(function (response) {
            $scope.res = response.data;


         }).
      error(function (response){
            console.log(response);

            $scope.res = response.data;


         });


   };
```

Code Flow: `code flow coming to error() section and then printing null in web console.`

Error :

```
Response object coming null as well as getting this error in web console 

XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=56X9b1af&api_secret=d3XXXX&number=91XX50298011&brand=stayuncle. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Can someone help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the problem.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

The REST API server is not configured for CORS, therefore, you are not allowed to access that URL from any origin other than the https://api.nexmo.com/ domain. However, aren't you supposed to be using JSONP?

[Reference on CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

[Reference on JSONP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

Comment: I got your point. Please suggest me what should i do to resolve this issue. Can please make changes in my code ?  it would be great help

Comment: Changes to your code will not make a difference if the server does not support JSONP or CORS.

Comment: this is api which i am using . https://docs.nexmo.com/index.php/verify/verify    Can you please look into this and suggest me some work around

Comment: @Nand, he already recommended that you use JSONP. 

But there is another concern as to whether you are building this app for yourself to use locally or if it will be hosted online because you do not want to put your secret into javascript that will be exposed to others. If your application will be public facing you will need to build a server side component to authorize the user and then make the api call to Nexmo.

Comment: @PhillipShipley  I tried with 
$scope.res=$http.jsonp("https://api.nexmo.com/verify/json?api_key=56aXXXaf&api_secret=d3XXXX41&number=919650298011&brand=stayuncle&callback=JSON_CALLBACK")

but response object coming undefined. Is there anything that I missed?

Comment: @Nand You seem to be ignoring comments in this thread. You need to find out how `api.nexmo.com` supports JSOP by reading their documentation and then send a request with the correct URL they require. Also, stop assigning the `$http.jsonp()` function to `$scope.res`. That is not what you want, and it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Brett It's your comment only through which I come to know about jsonp so I added  callback=JSON_CALLBACK in my REST URL.I searched for nexmo api but didn't find any particular documentation over jsonp.I tried hard but couldn't get about what you suggesting to me to do.Can you please help me to find some nexmo api which supported jsonp.It would be great help.